Ubuntu Server: Why would I be able to access Docker services, but not native ones on my local network?
I just built a new server to replace my older one and did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04.1, transferred all of my data, and went through all of the process of setting up my services, using a mix of docker and native services installed through apt. For the most part everything went as expected, but as the title says, I can't access any of the native services over the local network using the ip address and port (eg: http://<server-ip>:<port>), but I can access them using the external URL I have pointing to them (for the few that I have one set up for). And the weird thing is that my docker services work using both the ip address and port or the external URL.
I have no idea what to be causing this. Has anyone ever experienced anything like this before?
EDIT:
As requested, here is the output of docker ps:
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                   PORTS                                                    NAMES
176df3c42d4c   fallenbagel/jellyseerr:latest                        "/sbin/tini -- pnpm …"   18 hours ago   Up 7 minutes             192.168.1.3:5055->5055/tcp                               jellyseerr
50b07deee3dd   ghcr.io/immich-app/immich-server:release             "tini -- /bin/bash s…"   21 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   192.168.1.3:2283->2283/tcp                               immich_server
ed31f3b63292   2e2cb40c55b8                                         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   5432/tcp                                                 immich_postgres
2bc81795c57b   redis:6.2-alpine                                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   21 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   6379/tcp                                                 immich_redis
ad09f6b31664   ghcr.io/immich-app/immich-machine-learning:release   "tini -- ./start.sh"     21 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)                                                            immich_machine_learning
2ac1a3bc2669   nextcloud/aio-apache:latest                          "/start.sh /usr/bin/…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11000->11000/tcp                         nextcloud-aio-apache
09626bed6ef0   nextcloud/aio-notify-push:latest                     "/start.sh"              22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)                                                            nextcloud-aio-notify-push
903fb028f53f   nextcloud/aio-nextcloud:latest                       "/start.sh /usr/bin/…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   9000/tcp                                                 nextcloud-aio-nextcloud
8c70985c4893   nextcloud/aio-docker-socket-proxy:latest             "/start.sh"              22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)                                                            nextcloud-aio-docker-socket-proxy
191a3675c062   nextcloud/aio-fulltextsearch:latest                  "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                                       nextcloud-aio-fulltextsearch
ed17e7f8c462   nextcloud/aio-redis:latest                           "/start.sh"              22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   6379/tcp                                                 nextcloud-aio-redis
fadc6c646b84   nextcloud/aio-postgresql:latest                      "/start.sh"              22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   5432/tcp                                                 nextcloud-aio-database
32daa0a87f36   nextcloud/aio-collabora:latest                       "/start-collabora-on…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   9980/tcp                                                 nextcloud-aio-collabora
57539b73781d   searxng/searxng:latest                               "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes             192.168.1.3:8080->8080/tcp                               searxng
ad53dcae7eb3   valkey/valkey:7-alpine                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes             6379/tcp                                                 redis
06f8439c2b8e   nextcloud/all-in-one:latest                          "/start.sh"              22 hours ago   Up 7 minutes (healthy)   80/tcp, 8443/tcp, 9000/tcp, 192.168.1.4:8080->8080/tcp   nextcloud-aio-mastercontainer
0a7d81a8983a   jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest                      "/init"                  23 hours ago   Up 7 minutes             192.168.1.4:80-81->80-81/tcp, 192.168.1.4:443->443/tcp   nginx-proxy-manager-nginixproxymanager-1
111220fe43b3   jc21/mariadb-aria:latest                             "/scripts/run.sh"        23 hours ago   Up 7 minutes             3306/tcp                                                 nginx-proxy-manager-db-1

Also, new information: forcing the native services to bind to the ipv4 address does not allow access
EDIT2:
As requested, here is the configuration of the firewall in front of the server, running on a ubiquity unifi router:
Name         From       Port      Forward IP / Port
Nginx        Any        80        192.168.1.4:80
Nginx2       Any        443       192.168.1.4:443

If it helps, this is what the output of iptables -L looks like on the new server:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_INP  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWX  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWI  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LIBVIRT_FWO  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere            

Chain DOCKER (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.23.0.2           tcp dpt:5055
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.21.0.3           tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:81
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.19.0.5           tcp dpt:2283
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.22.0.7           tcp dpt:11000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.22.0.9           tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.123.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.123.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain LIBVIRT_INP (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:67

Chain LIBVIRT_OUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:68


And how exactly did you set up this external URL? Nginx or Apache and proxy pass?

I use nginx proxy manager

So it's not as if these services are all directly exposed to all networks. Run sudo netstat -tnlp, you'll probably find some of these are only listening on localhost.

As it turns out, not quite. They're all just only listening on the server's ipv6 address... I don't really see a need for ipv6 on my home network, guess I'll put off learning it again.

Run docker ps then copy-paste the output by Editing the question, it will help to see ports.

@A.L posted it above, along with some new information.

So I figured out what was wrong. The answer actually turned out to be shockingly simple: the nftables service was disabled. Seems everything gets blocked when it isn't running but docker does some kind of magic let its stuff work. Just in case anyone else ever faces this problem, make sure nftables is enabled and running

"docker does some kind of magic let its stuff work" See https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/ "On Linux, Docker creates iptables and ip6tables rules to implement network isolation, port publishing and filtering."

docker ps shows different cases for PORTS:
192.168.1.3:5055
This means that this port is accessible through the 192.168.1 subnet. You should be able to call it from the host or another computer on the same network (its IP address must start with 192.168.1) with curl http://192.168.1.3:5055/ --output /dev/null or by opening this URL in your browser. But not from another computer.
0.0.0.0:11000
This means that this port is accessible through every subnet. You should be able to call it from any computer with curl http://<server-ip>:11000 --output /dev/null or by opening this URL in your browser.
5432/tcp
This port is not accessible from the host or Internet. (it may be accessible from containers on the same host but this is out of scope here)
These settings depend on how you defined the ports when using docker run or docker compose. Disallowing access from Internet allow you to restrict the access through a proxy, and by using something like fail2ban, you could block scripts that send thousands of requests.
See also the Docker documentation about ports: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/docker-concepts/running-containers/publishing-ports/

Well yes, but everything related to docker is working fine just like it did with the same configuration on the old server I migrated everything from. It's only the non-docker services (for example, jellyfin installed through apt) which are now inaccessible over the local network post-migration. The only reason I mentioned docker is because I can't see how it makes sense that I can access services running in docker over the local network but not the ones running natively under Ubuntu.
Also, everything is behind a firewall with only nginix proxy manager directly exposed to the internet

Docker will open ports on the firewall automatically, that may make the difference you see. Please add these details in the question itself, with the port of Jelllyfin and the configuration of the firewall.

I can do that once I get back home, but I should mention that the firewall I'm referring to is a separate box, hasn't changed at all pre or post migration to the new server hardware, and never touched local to local traffic to begin with.

Added the info to the question
